# Subtract Max, Min Date by Group in Impala

Tags: hadoop, impala

I have a query where I find the max and min date by user in impala:

```
select max(id_date) as last_tran
       ,min(id_date) as first_tran
       ,user
from table_1 a 
join table_2 d
on a.id = d.id
group by 3
```

I want to then subtract the min and max date by user.

In Impala I tried using the `date_sub` function but it does not work.

```
select date_sub(last_tran, first_tran) as date_len
, user
from
(select max(id_date) as last_tran
       ,min(id_date) as first_tran
       ,user
from table_1 a 
join table_2 d
on a.id= d.id
group by 3) time
group by 1,2
```

It seems that the `date_sub` functions 2nd argument has to be an integer representing days.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work the `datediff` function should be used like so:

```
select datediff(last_tran, first_tran) as date_len
, user
from
(select max(id_date) as last_tran
       ,min(id_date) as first_tran
       ,user
from table_1 a 
join table_2 d
on a.id= d.id
group by 3) time
group by 1,2
```

The function returns days between the start date and end date. From the [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) it seems like the return value of days cannot be changed.